# How to kill threads in Julia?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am running three processes simultaneously by executing them through an Ipython notebook. I want to know what is the best way to kill any or all of the threads whenever I want.  I see that interrupting kernal in the notebook stops just the process 1.

Answer (score 2):

From the Julia documentation:

[`interrupt([pids...])`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/parallel/#Base.interrupt)

Interrupt the current executing task on the specified workers. This is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-C on the local machine. If no arguments are given, all workers are interrupted.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness, `[pids]` is the vector being returned by `addprocs()`, e.g. when doing `addprocs(7)`, you should get back a `Vector{Any}` of length 7 with the ids of each remote process (2,3,...,8).